# Django get the number of objects in each day of a month

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get the number of objects in each day of a month, using the following in view:

```
startIng = datetime.datetime(2019,1,1)
endIng = datetime.datetime(2019,2,1)
aDayDelta = timedelta(days=1)
totalDays = (endIng - startIng).days
days = [startIng + k*aDayDelta for k in range(totalDays)] 
for mydays in days:
    datem = Daily_movements.objects.filter(mov_date__startswith=(mydays))
...
```

but I get nothing,

trying i e:

```
datem = Daily_movements.objects.filter(mov_date__startswith=datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 9, 0, 0))
```

I get the perfect result for this given date

TIA for any help

Comment: Well it is easy to get the count of the objects, just put .count() after the filter function. `datem_count = Daily_movements.objects.filter(mov_date__startswith=datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 9, 0, 0)).count()
`

Comment: how it will counts while I get 0 results !? the question not about count(), it is about the queryset filter using list of dates

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can filter on the year and month, and then obtain a `Count` per day, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractDay

qs = Daily_movements.objects.filter(
    mov_date__year=year,
    mov_date__month=month
).annotate(
    day=ExtractDay('mov_date'),
).values(
    'day'
).annotate(
    n=Count('pk')
).order_by('day')
```

This will result in a `QuerySet` that wraps dictionaries with two items: `'day'`, which denotes the day, and `n`, which denotes the value. For example:

```
<QuerySet [
   { 'day': 1, 'n': 12 },
   { 'day': 3, 'n': 13 },
   { 'day': 4, 'n': 2 },
   { 'day': 6, 'n': 14 },
   { 'day': 10, 'n': 25 }
]>
```

We can then convert this to a `Counter` for example: a dictionary that defaults to zero for unknown keys, like:

```
from collections import Counter

data = Counter({d['day']: d['n'] for d in qs})
```

We can convert it to a list with:

```
from calendar import monthrange

__, ds = monthrange(year, month)
result = [data[i] for i in range(1, ds+1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this will not give a result of the day 5 (in your example) because I'm looking to query from the list of (each day of a month) as I said in my question, so I want to get 0 records for the day 5 i.e

Comment: @Hisham: that's where the counter part comes in in the last code fragment.

Comment: datem= Daily_movements.objects.filter(mov_date__year=2019,mov_date__month=2).annotate(day=ExtractDay('mov_date'),).values('day').annotate(n=Count('pk')).order_by('day')
    data = Counter({d['day']: d['n'] for d in datem})

<QuerySet [{'n': 19, 'day': 2}, {'n': 13, 'day': 3}, {'n': 27, 'day': 5}, {'n': 18, 'day': 6}, {'n': 14, 'day': 7}, {'n': 19, 'day': 9}, {'n': 10, 'day': 10}, {'n': 1, 'day': 25}]> 
Counter({5: 27, 2: 19, 9: 19, 6: 18, 7: 14, 3: 13, 10: 10, 25: 1}) 

as you see for example I get nothing from day 8 of the month where I want to get: {'n': 0, 'day': 8}

Comment: @Hisham: of course, this is a consequence of the *closed world assumption*. But as said in the answer, you can "patch" that Python/Django level. You thus can not do much to patch the query, since simple SQL queries can not represent that, but you an simply amend the result of the queryset.

Comment: I will try to loop through a list of days, days = [ x for x in range(1,32)], then do a query: datem = Daily_movements.objects.filter(mov_date__year=2019, mov_date__month=2,mov_date__day=days[i]).annotate ...

Comment: @Hisham: no, just make a dictionary, or a counter, here you start querying the database way too much, this is basically multiplying the number of queries.

Comment: @Hisham: I honestly still don't see what is wrong with using a counter here, after all, a `Counter` is something that stores the count of things.

Comment: this is great, even I couldn't fit it perfectly yet, but I guess I will play around it